# Add button in UITabBarController in Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, xcode-storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have the following storyboard:

[image: storyboard]

In the tab bar controller I have a add button with a segue to a view controller. I need to use the method "prepareForSegue:" because I need to transfer an object but in the Repositories Table  View doesn't fire the method.

How can I detect the method "prepareForSegue:" in the Repositories Table View? Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean "detect the method"? Just override it, right?

Comment: can you put your code here...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose for "detect the method `prepareForSegue`" you mean "identify the right segue in the `prepareForSegue` method".

You do this by using `[segue identifier]` and the string comparison method `isEqualToString:` to compare it to what you set the Identifier to be in storyboard.

Also, make sure that the button, table view cell, button or other element is attached to the right segue. You can of course do that in storyboard as well. If you need to do it in code e.g. because the button is created programmatically, you will have to call the segue yourself. In the button handler you just use

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:"SegueIdentifier" sender:self];
```

Comment: Hi Mundi, no, it's identify the right segue, so the button is in the navigation item of the tab bar controller and i can't detect when the method "prepareForSegue:" is fired. In my Repositories Table View I have the method and when I puss the add button it isn't fired.